# Graph Comparison hash function

Tags: machine-learning, graph, deep-learning, hash, graph-neural-network

I'm currently working on a graph machine-learning application covering three stages. In the first stage, a model performs community detection on graphs. The second stage involves a model trained to compare graphlets. I need to create a dictionary containing unique graphlets. The second model can output a similarity score, enabling the application to determine if graphlets are similar. Is there a way to compute a hash for such objects so that I would not have to iterate through the whole dictionary to check if an isomorphic graph is already present? I know of the Weisfeiler-Lehman process being able to output hashes; however, as I already have a trained model to compare graphs, I wanted to know if there was a way to create a hash table as the basis for my dictionary.

I really appreciate any help.